# Create string in one character at a time with loop

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a string of every hour in the week starting at `0`. The string would be *167* characters long and consist of *0/1* for every character representing *true/false* for that hour.

I know you can edit strings as so :

```
$foo = "123456789";
echo $foo[0]; // outs 1
echo $foo[1]; //outs 2

$foo[0] = 1;
$foo[1] = 1;

echo $foo[0]; // outs 1
echo $foo[1]; // outs 1
```

So I assumed I could set a blank string and use the same method to 'build' it.  So I am running a loop from *0-167* and while doing so checking if the 'hour' is in the `$hours` array.  If it is I set it to *1* in my string... if not it is set to *0*. Problems :

**1.** This does not work by setting `$inputHours = ''` and it just creates
    an array instead of the string I want.

**2.** Is there a more optimized manner to check if an hour is set other
    than using `in_array` *167* times?

```
//array of selected hours
$hours = array(1, 25, 34, 76, 43)

//create selected hours string from selection
$inputHours = '';

for ($x = 0; $x < 168; $x++) {
    $inputHours[$x] = in_array($x, $hours) ? 1 : 0; 
}
```

Expected output would be `$inputHours = '0011010101...'` depending if set for a total lenth of **167** characters.

Comment: curious, what's the string going to be used for, keeping the select hours array seems more efficient

Comment: I have been trying to think of a good way to store selected hours for an entire week in sql for rows.  I originally had 7 rows of 24... one for each day, but queries were taking longer than I wanted because I had to join those rows for each 'result' if I wanted to display an entire weeks schedule for each.  I thought of this method today.  Easy inserts, easy queries, one row per instead of 7, and reading values is as easy as $week[hour#]

Comment: bad idea, create hours table

Comment: Explain your thoughts and reasoning - this is MUCH quicker and easier than having 168 columns OR 7 rows of 24 columns in the database. I also have no need for query'ing specific hours only the set as a whole.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can concatenate characters in one string with `.=` operator and check condition using ternary operator (`[expression] ? [true] : [false]`) with `in_array()` function:

```
for($x = 0; $x < 168; $x++)
    $inputHours .= in_array($x, $hours) ? 1 : 0;
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/244822)